# Did Rama see all women as his mother?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Kausalya was the mother of Rama.

Did Rama show to all other women the same respect that he showed to Kausalya?

Comment: I do not understand your Q in what sense do you mean treat other women?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu In his perception, giving same value to other women as he gives to Kausalya.

Comment: yes because He was maryaada purushottama and seeing paranari as mother is our ageold culture

Comment: @Pratimaputra No, both are different, a person who reads Valmiki Ramayana can understand it. Because it is not a surface question.

Comment: seeing as mother means not  having any type of attraction to other women. None can love any woman as much as he loves his mother

Comment: @Pratimaputra Yeah, there is a mention I hope.

Comment: What sort of mention would you like exactly?

Comment: @Archit I expect a mention like, Rama treats/respects all other women except Sita as his own mother.

Comment: @hanugm: somewhat - The exceedingly strong Rama bears himself to all other Queens, as he exercises his behaviour towards his mother, Kausalya. The valiant and pious Rama who is devoted to Dasartha and free from all sense of importance treats all those **women as his mothers on whom Dasaratha has even once bestowed a single glance**. [2.118.5-6](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga118/ayodhya_118_frame.htm). Well you can’t say he saw others as his mom but he maintained respect eg. The reason he kills Bali, bharata says not to hit manthara because Rama will be angry (VR 2.78.21-23)